# How to React-Admin Use JsonServer Get My express API "The response to 'getList' must be like { data : [...] }

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, react-admin, json-server

I use jsonServerProvider But I can not get my express Api data

**error code**

```
The response to 'getList' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'getList'
```

**My React-Admin ./dataProvider...**

```
import jsonServerProvider from "ra-data-json-server";
import {fetchUtils} from "react-admin"
import axios from 'axios'

const fetchJson = (url, options = {}) => {
  if (!options.headers) {
      options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
  }
  // add your own headers here
  options.headers.set('X-Custom-Header', 'foobar');
  options.headers.set('withCredentials', true);
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider("http://localhost:5000/periodical/api",fetchJson);

export default dataProvider;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doMKN.png)

**My categoryList...**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  EditButton,
  Create,
  Edit,
  SimpleForm,
  SelectInput,
  TextInput,
  DeleteButton,
} from "react-admin";


const CategorysTitle = ({ record }) => {
  return <span>Post {record ? `"${record.title}"` : ""}</span>;
};

export const CategorysList = (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <EditButton />
      <DeleteButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

**My NodeJS express...**

```
router.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await CATEGORY.get();
        res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count')
        res.set('X-Total-Count', data)
        console.log(data);
        return res.status(200).json({ data });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUIPh.png)

**My Postman...**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx6oE.png)

**My Web...**

```
The response to 'getList' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'getList'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omf3f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your API to return an array at its top level like so:
[
{
"id": "C01",
"name": "name01"
},
{
"id": "C02",
"name": "name02"
}
]

so that you can safely discard the ...{ "data": [... from being returned by your API.

That "data" and "total" labels seen in react-admin documentation are referring to the dataProvider's job for visualisation. See it on ra-data-json-server package: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/1b6967f3367b13a6675de7047bd9385dc36a8db5/packages/ra-data-json-server/src/index.js#L113

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).